# Automatically generate videos from template

Tags: windows, automation

I need to create a number of videos from a template - they will have an image background, and then 1-4 separate videos appearing over the top. Something like this:

[image]

The catch - these videos will need to be automatically generated in some way by a server.

Is there some software out there that will spit out video files according to a template like this? 
I'd need a way to set the background image, as well as the number and position of the overlay videos.

This will ideally be done on a Windows server, but I can use other operating systems if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script that generates a custom ffmpeg command based on inputs provided could do this. You'd need to construct a filter complex with scale/crop filters for each video and multiple overlay filters with time conditions for the compositing. If you're willing to learn and trial it out, grab the Win static binaries [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and start with some [basic](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide) [guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos).

Comment: Thanks - I've found a very similar request over on StackOverflow which gives me a starting point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390714/superimposing-two-videos-onto-a-static-image